# Creating a custom ODBC / OLE driver in C#

Tags: c#, excel, odbc, oledb, driver

Does anyone know how to create an ODBC or OLE driver preferably in C#?

What I want to do is creating a custom data source which I can use in Excel and Access. Or do think of another way how to do this?

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: custom datasource pointing to what?

Comment: I want to get data from a custom webservice but use it as a data source.

Comment: We have same need. Write ODBC driver in C#.  I spent several hours but cannot find any sample online. We only know C# ... and writing ODBC driver in C would be expensive compared to higher level language such as C# . Anyone here who has sample odbc in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simplified version of OLE DB Driver in C#. In the article below, the sample provides an access to in-memory array.

This is a good starting point in C#.

http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/10/oledb-simple-provider-c-custom.html